# Terraform keyvault delete protection not work as expected

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

When such configuration is used:

```
    module "key_vault" {
      for_each = var.STAGES
    
      resourceName           = "kv-${each.value}-${local.resource_name_suffix}"
      ...

      purgeProtectionEnabled = true
    }
```

Then when for some reason secrets should be deleted. Restore gets error:

```
Error: keyvault.BaseClient#RecoverDeletedSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=409 Code="Conflict" Message="Secret AzureAiApiKey is currently being deleted." InnerError={"code":"Object
IsBeingDeleted"}
```

So how to make RecoverDeletedSecret delay or trigger when delete is completed?

Comment: An impotant thing here is to make sure you give more context. For example, I have no information about the module you are using. Additionally, I don't know where and how the module variable is used or for what. So please edit the question with **all the relevant** details if you expect an answer.

Comment: Thx @MarkoE but then you could list here which aspects could influence this behavior. As I understand there is no options to wait till object is deleted. It could be very good if such option would be in terraform.

Comment: I cannot list anything as I have no idea where the module is coming from, what is inside it, are there any issues with variables, default variable values, provider versions etc.

Answer (score 1):

According go [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10454) github issue, this should already be fixed with version 2.49.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 2.49.0"
}
```

Please always try to use the **latest** azurerm provider. I’ve seen many errors I couldn’t wrap my head around. And more often than not, things are already fixed in later versions of the provider.